# File not found with Servlet RequestDispatcher and forward()

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet that exists at path:

`/myservlet1/doit`

When this servlet is called, I wish it to forward the request (at the end) to a second servlet called:

`/myservlet2/finish`

I have coded:

```
ServletContext ctx = this.getServletContext().getContext("/myservlet2");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/myservlet2/finish");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

But I fail with the indication "`/myservlet2/finish`" was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whe we execute the `getRequestDispatcher` we provide a URL that is *relative* to the context of the dispatcher.  Since we asked for the servlet context for `/myservlet2` then when we ask for a request dispatcher, the path supplied to `getRequestDispatcher` is relative to the context.  This means that the correct code fragment should be:

```
ServletContext ctx = this.getServletContext().getContext("/myservlet2");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/finish");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```